# Why is the 'Polarity of Power' thesis less relevant and meaningful in the present architecture of 'Balance of Power'

Tags: international-relations, political-theory, geopolitics, power

There used to be a time when concept of World power had a nature to be concentrated in one country or a group of countries, but in current setup collective security is being more prominent in contrast to polarity of power.

I was wondering what factors have caused this shift from Polarity of power to Balance of power in World politics ?

EDIT: Description of the question.

In present context, we see that at international level, still powerful states (power=military and technical advancement) dominate and modify the decisions taken at international arena (in a way it would not be so unreasonable to say that one kind of Anarchy is there at global level), BUT having said so, still its clearly visible that the same powerful nation-states prefer to go for many regional and international agreements with 'equal distribution' principle, though it seems to be contrary to their dominant nature. This has resulted in a new setup of Balance of power which seems to be based more on 'collective security concept' rather than on 'Polarity of power' concept. My curiosity is in knowing the reason behind this shift ? what factors may have caused this change of political thinking ?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain that *Balance of Power* and *Polarity* are that different. Polarity, in my understanding, just describes the nature of the balance of power. Whether or not it is a unipolar, bipolar, or multipolar balance of power.

Comment: Or, are you saying that the balance of power in the world is less concentrated in the "hands" of a single state and more spread out? Looking to institutions like NATO, the UN, and the EU as examples?

Comment: Yes, @BillKeller ..your second comment describes the soul of my question. Moreover I added an EDIT in my question to make it more elaborative.

Comment: I think you need to clarify, because what you seem to be asking at one point is about the empirical reality of the world "Why are there no longer poles?" and at another point "Why do people not talk about there being poles, irrespective of the reality of the existence of polarity?" The two questions are very different. Also, the second one is not true, at least in academic and policy circles. There are active and ongoing discussions of the roles of polarity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad. The best answer would be a review of *at least* four major tomes of Political Science, and frankly who has time for that. You're welcome to sit in on my introduction to IR course, if you would like. We'll cover all of this over the course of a semester.

Comment: Actually, better yet, Taylor Fravel has a course available online. Take that. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/political-science/17-418-field-seminar-international-relations-theory-fall-2011/